# How to obtain Title of Configurable Option from Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Item_Option

Tags: model, configurable-product

Inside an observer I've got instances of `Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Item_Option` that are from a `Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Item` via `::getOptions()`:

```
/** @var $item Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Item */
$options = $item->getOptions();
foreach ($options as $index => $option) {
    $id    = $option->getId();
    $value = $option->getValue();
    $title = $option-> ??? ;
}
```

How can I retrieve the title of such an option represented by such **Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Item_Option**?

Comment: So far I've learned that titles for these options aren't with these options but with the product having these options.

Answer (score 0):

you use this:

```
$productModel = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
$attr = $productModel->getResource()->getAttribute($option->getId());
if ($attr->usesSource()) {
    $title = $attr->getSource()->getOptionText($option->getValue());
}
```

Comment: I was not looking for product attributes but item options.